# Can I use oracle sql loader to update a column?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

I have data in a table(3 columns out of which 2 columns already have data). I have a text file which has three fields. Now, can I use sql loader to update the third column in table using the value in 3rd field in the text file?

Comment: can you give a hint how to do so? Thank you

Comment: write your update statement in quotes after the field name with the conditions you need

Comment: @vkp: SQL\*Loader can **not** update rows, it can only insert new rows.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name..thank you. I thought any statement could be used.

Comment: So is there no way i can use sql loader in this case? other than creating a new table, loading the data in that table first and then using a procedure to update the main table accordingly.

Comment: Or use a file as an external table.https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/et_concepts.htm#i1009127

Comment: @newbie_123..one other way is to drop the original table and select from two files when loading

Comment: @vkp , dropping the table would be good but in my case it won't be feasible as this is not just one time process, I need to do it on daily bases. Moreover I may not have drop access.

Comment: @Gary_W , I am not familiar with external tables, may be i need to dig in a bit. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only two ways I know for making this work are:

1. Using an external table, which allows the file to be treated as a table which can be queried, and which can be used as part of an update statement. Excellent performance and flexibility!
2. Using SQL*Loader to insert into a view against which is defined an "INSTEAD OF INSERT" trigger which executes an update statement. This means performing row-by-row processing, so it is slower than external tables. It is not very elegant, and requires PL/SQL of course, but makes the execution of arbitrary SQL statements based on SQL*Loader inserts possible.